# Download File in Java Spring rest api

Tags: java, spring, file

I want to download a file and for that I have written this code:

```
public void downoadResume(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletResponse response) {
try {
    Applicant applicant = applicantService.getOne(id);
    File file = new File(DocumentConstants.DOCUMENTS_PATH + "/" + applicant.getOriginalDocPath());
    // get your file as InputStream
    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
    // copy it to response's OutputStream
    org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
    is.close();
    response.flushBuffer();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

But I am getting this kind of response instead of file, please check:

```
PK!�?�*��[Content_Types].xml �(���Oo�@��H|k���i�8=��X*���8Y���3i�o��I�RLHs���罟��3��g��G�hc��e5?
�Z|�ߕE?��Q.��P\�޿��7    ��ꀵX�OR�^?WX�?O���"��K����� �&�R�@��VC̦��QkG��3��%��P7�[�Z���Պ�T>�ʥ�9T\�݃+���1�thO�n�����dk�xP���g���&���g��pƦ���V-���3���O��a�?ġ�H���NZ�?c�˓qz�V2Y�3b��k����'��F/}(�i�ߞ`�{��wK�ۦ�]?����Z��w"���߿�r��p�<����g�x!>
��H!�9�}/=
���a�<����#:����� ^ ���gQ'sȒGe7�x���x���h�K��G̻ޑ���9C���o٭��/��PK!���N_rels/.rels �(����JA���a�}7�
"���H�w"����w̤ھ�� �P�^����O֛���;�<�aYՠ؛`G�kxm��PY�[��g
Gΰino�/<���<�1��ⳆA$>"f3��\�ȾT�?I    S?���������W����Y
ig�@��X6_�]7~
f��ˉ�ao�.b*lI�r?j)�,l0�%?�b�
6�i���D�_���,   �   ���|u�Z^t٢yǯ;!Y,}{�C��/h>��PK!����g�word/_rels/document.xml.rels �(����N�0��H�C�;�:`�n@�����N[��U�{{¦u۲K/��G����?���:��*4)K���H�+S��-{��c�#arQ�?�������b�� ��+��E>�q)+���?,AcƟ(�Z?m�!?E|8����`ӽ��<O�?��~�j|���Q�J�#ʥCGJp0�A�W�2a��m��s2~��OG����C��}�W������    a�z֯�n��H��?KG�?���e�cު�"�I�f�'�7,^?�����1r�'�;��*!���Fϔ�}�n,�?���?ܜ`Е��PQ,Q�?K���x߀��)�WT>)�:�88
5���;<oY
```

Can you please tell me what wrong I have done in this code?

Comment: Why are you returning void instead of returning an ResponseEntity. Also you show how you have mapped your controller.

Comment: its a zip file and you're not specifying the mime type

Comment: @WeareBorg-  I have tried with returning an ResponseEntity also, still getting the same result

Comment: @FredericHenri- Can you please tell me how to define that ?

Comment: @FredericHenri- I searched that and added this code 
 response.setContentType(new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(file));
Is this okay ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the response headers and content-type which triggers the browser to treat the response content as a file and not as a web page:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");      
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=download.xlsx");
```

Comment: @DSF- I tried this for downloading an .docx by replacing the code like this 
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.docx");

Although a file gets downloaded, but it doesn't saved as an .docx file. A very long name is used as file name.

Comment: You can have a different behaviour depends on what browser you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are downloading an xlsx file, Try the code below:

```
    public void downoadResume(@PathVariable("id") int id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        Applicant applicant = applicantService.getOne(id);
        File file = new File(DocumentConstants.DOCUMENTS_PATH + "/" + applicant.getOriginalDocPath());
response.reset();
            response.resetBuffer();
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.xlsx");
        // get your file as InputStream
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        // copy it to response's OutputStream
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
        is.close();
        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

Comment: No I was trying to download .docx file not the xlsx file, is there any other way for defining it for different kind of files

Comment: Can you try `Files.probeContentType(DocumentConstants.DOCUMENTS_PATH + "/" + applicant.getOriginalDocPath())` as content type